# Call to a member function on a non-object error when sql query returns 0

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have the following query using php's PDO

```
$STH = $DBH->query('
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS hits FROM table WHERE column = "' .$variable. '"
');
```

The table is empty, would this have something to do with the error?
Does it have something to do with `hits` being 0?

I am selecting the data from a MSSQL database.

Comment: Can you post your complete relevant code ? Where you initialize `$DBH` class object ?

Comment: `$DBH` is not a valid object to call the `query` method. It doesn't have difference if the query returns 0 or not.

Comment: Ok, I've solved it, I swapped out all `'` for `"` and visa versa. I think this is a sql problem. Dangit now I have to do this for all instances like this. I used the `'` so I could have inputs containing the character `'` but I'll just have to find another way to do this ;)

Answer (score 2):

It simple means that `$DBH` is not an object so it is not connected that you have 0 as result.

You should first create `$DBH` object and then run `query` method

Comment: I have a file called 'db_connect.php' which I link all my pages to. The $DBH object has been classified there. I know it works because other sql queries and prepared statements work fine.

Comment: Try to add `var_dump($DBH);` just before running the query and show us result.

Comment: I get the following: object(PDO)#1 (0) { }

Comment: Are you really sure problem is in that line? Can you run any other query that you previously run in your app before or after this query? Are you sure that you use everywhere `$DBH` in capital letters?

Comment: yup, if I remove the above code, the other queries run fine

Comment: please edit the question and add some more code, for example  those queries that work fine in the same place. At the moment we have too little data to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the use of the single and double quotations:

```
$STH = $DBH->query("
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE column = '" .$variable. "'
");
```

I used the single quotations `'` so that inputs including single quotations would still be valid. This does not work with MSSQL commands.